# Using Generic Types in Window.Resources

Tags: wpf

I am trying to use Generic Types in Windows.Resources section in XAML code. To attach the notification for a collection of objects my generic collection inherits from ObservableCollection as shown below:

```
public class PresentationModalCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    {
        public PresentationModalCollection(List<T> list) : base(list)
        {

        }

    }
```

There is an extension method that returns a ObservableCollection for List as shown below:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static PresentationModalCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this List<T> list)
        {
            return new PresentationModalCollection<T>(list); 
        }
    }
```

Now, I want to use the PresentationModalCollection in my Window.Resources like shown below:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <LearningWPF:PresentationModalCollection x:Key="customers">
            <LearningWPF:Customer FirstName="Mohammad" LastName="Azam" />
        </LearningWPF:PresentationModalCollection>


    </Window.Resources>
```

Of course, the above code does not work. Is there any way of doing the above without having to create a class CustomerCollection which inherits from the ObservableCollection?

Comment: I think it is not supported in .NET 3.5 but for .NET 4.0 it will be supported. Check out the following link => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489466(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike Hillberg has some [extensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehillberg/archive/2006/10/06/LimitedGenericsSupportInXaml.aspx) that can help out with it and work pretty well.  I agree that creating a CustomerCollection and collection type for each type you wanted to wrap would be overbearing.  [Sacha Barber](http://sachabarber.net/?p=399) also has a solution to use Generics in XAML, but his website seems to have surpassed his bandwidth limit for the moment.